# iPhone doesn't complete loading iTunes library via Home Sharing

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, itunes, iphone, home-sharing

I've been trying to use iTunes / Music.app on my iPhone 4S running latest iOS 7.1.1 (11D201) and access the "Home Shared" iTunes library that my Mac Pro (10.9.3) makes available on my network. No problem with my other computers accessing this library and my AppleTV doesn't have any problems either. However, though my iPhone sees the library on Home Sharing, when I select the library and it starts to load I get to about half-way on the circle / pie-chart before it just stops. No errors, nothing; if I leave it alone it doesn't resolve itself. In other words, I can't access my shared library from my phone.

I've tried rebooting the phone, killing all other applications and in general making sure that the phone isn't under any stress. Nothing works. Though I have seen mention of this problem on the internet I haven't seen any solutions. Worth noting that it doesn't work on my wife's iPhone 5, either.

I have seen mentions on forums about re-logging on to Home Sharing and also checking the network settings of the WiFi router. The former doesn't solve it and the latter doesn't sound correct since it does get half way before failing; in an experiment, the pie-chart status circle will stop MUCH sooner if there is a network issue.

Any ideas? Anyone else experiencing this issue?

Comment: I get this ALL the time, on both my phone and iPad.  Our 3 Apple TVs can access the Home Sharing just fine, but iPhones/iPads have serious trouble.  Sometimes it does actually load, but it takes minutes to do so (like 10 minutes or more!).  I've been meaning to submit it as a bug to Apple, but just haven't gotten around to it yet.  Please feel free to do so, if no one has anything substantial to help here.

Comment: @jimtut, raised on Apple bug report as #17469584. I don't think Apple supports upvoting, but worth giving it a try!

Comment: You can't view other people's bugs (not that I can tell), so I finally submitted my own bug too.  Please post back here if they respond to your bug, and I'll do the same.

Answer (score -1):

I experienced this and spent months with apple before I found the work around. First this was on a PC so if a Mac not sure if it will work. First disable ipv6 in your network settings. More likely than not u will never need this function activated anyways. Second in your router's settings (assuming u can login yourself. If not contact your Internet provider for either the info to login or tell them what u want done) specify all the ports related to home sharing from apple are open. Apple has a list specific. Lastly make sure your router is set to channel 11. I did all three steps one at a time. The last one finally got EVERYTHING working so that may be all u need but I really wasn't in the mood to go back and forth all day again. Hope this helps. Cuz apple support was a waste of time

Comment: I tried this but didn't solve the problem, unfortunately.